# Anyone doing here WPF with MVC/MVP pattern?

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

Would you mind tell me why? :)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839118/composite-guidance-for-wpf-mvvm-vs-mvp

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do MVC using the [Paul Stovell Magellan Framework](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan) (excellent)

But was not well suited for my project. In fact, I believe that MVC is not a well pattern for a desktop app.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: ah well I was just and again running against a mvvm wall... so I wanted to know about wpf + mvc but its a bad choice I think above all in .net we use MVP bit different. I can just hope josh smith is enlighting soon all our brains with enterprise solutions ;P

your 2 cent is enough at least for a 1 cent point ;-)

Comment: sorry I meant MVP not or MVC which is not suited for .NET.

Comment: Magellan can be a MVVMC, Im using Magellan+ReactiveUI and it is really great. Magellan Controllers for navigation and ReactiveUI for View behavior