# MVVM relations between viewmodel-view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, design-patterns

I am an newbie in wpf and mvvm. I can't answer a base question... What relations should be in my application between model,viewmodel, view... One view-one viewmodel, or one model-one viewmodel? Or may be one viewmodel-many view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- one or more models => one view model
- one view model => one view

Comment: Ok, thanks, and what principial differents between mvvm and mvp?

Comment: @Yuriy Mayorov, in MVP you have a Presenter which coordinates the interactions between the view and the model. There is no view model. In MVVM you don't have this Presenter and it is the view model which represents the abstraction of the view which can interact with the underlying model directly. And here's a [nice discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839118/composite-guidance-for-wpf-mvvm-vs-mvp) about those two patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A view has always a corresponding viewmodel. So the relation here is always "one view - one viewmodel". This viewmodel itself can have one or more models that provide the data, but it can also have one or more viewmodels as data provider. The point is that there can be way more viewmodel than views. Just to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [**Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)**](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Model-View-ViewModel%20Pattern&ProjectName=waf) article interesting. It discusses how the parts should be connected to each other.

Comment: No answer posted here, and the article linked does not appear to primarily (or even obviously) address the question.

Comment: The link seems to not work.