# How to pass instances to WPF Window class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Suppose I have 3 classes to handle all database related requests:

```
public class DB_A{}
public class DB_B{}
public class DB_C{}
```

and I got 2 windows to interact with user:

```
window1.xaml;window1.xaml.cs;
window2.xaml;window2.xaml.cs
```

as window1 & window2 need to interact with database, they need to use functions from previous 3 classes, I created a class DataHandler:

```
public class DataHandler
{
    public DB_A a;
    public DB_B b;
    public DB_C c;

    public DataHandler()
    {
        a = new DB_A();
        b = new DB_B();
        c = new DB_C();
    }

    //some functions... ...
}
```

now the class DataHandler can handle all database related request, and now i need to pass a instant of DataHandler to both window1 and window2.

I tried to re-write the constructor for both window1 and window2 with parameter, but it does not allow me to do that. After google i know that WPF window form does not allow constructor with parameter.

Is there any way to pass my DataHandler to the two window form classes?

Comment: Can't you set it as a property on both windows?

Comment: I actually misunderstood the concept of MVVM. Set it as property is the right way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `DataHandler` a singleton, and let the window classes access it.

```
public class DataHandler
{
    //singleton instance
    static DataHandler _instance = new DataHandler ();

    public DataHandler Instance
    {
          get { return _instance; }
    }
};
```

Then,

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
   DataHandler _dataHandler;

   public Window1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataHandler = DataHandler.Instance;
   }
}
```

Similarly, write other Window class.

Or even better is, apply some variant of MVP pattern, most likely, MVVM. Read these articles:

- [Composite Guidance for WPF : MVVM vs MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839118/composite-guidance-for-wpf-mvvm-vs-mvp)
- [WPF patterns : MVC, MVP or MVVM or…?](http://visualizationtools.net/default/wpf-patterns-mvc-mvp-or-mvvm-or/)
- [Model-View-Presenter Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx)
- [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx)

Comment: @zqkun: Yes. Of course. MVVM is the most natural pattern for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, there are multiple ways to do that,

1. you make your DataHandler a singleton. ( I do not like this one)
2. add a public static property to app.xaml.cs that has an instance of your DataHandler class and in your Windows’ constructor take that from app. (it’s a better approach)
3. add a ViewModel and let that view model present data to both Windows. (I prefer this one!)
   If you need an example let me know which one works for you and  I will provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make the DataHandler class to singleton and use it's methods on wherever you want, without re-instantiating the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can have parameters on your Window constructor. Alternatively you could pass it in through a property, set your DataHandler object to a public static property somewhere, or even just make your DataHandler a static class.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to accomplish this.

You can make `DataHandler` a singleton.

Since `DataHandler` has a parameterless constructor, you can create it in the application's resource dictionary, and let objects use `FindResource` to get it.

One pattern that you'll see pretty commonly, in implementations using the MVVM pattern, is that the view models contain a reference to shared objects, and windows get access to them through binding, though I doubt very much that you're using MVVM.

Comment: You are right, it's not good to use DataHandler in my case. After spending time to understand the MVVM concept, I passed the reference to view model, and it works fine.